# How to handle a multiple singles?

Tags: rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I'm writing messenger server on grpc with rxjava2 stubs, and I stuck on combining my singles.

I'm have tried some sort of

```
  val user:Single<User> = getUser()
  val conversation:Single<Conversation> = getConversation(user.blockingGet())
  return conversation.map{
      someMethod(user.blockingGet(), conversation.it())
      it
  }
```

It looks so unbeauty then all of the examples, so is there a way to combine all of this singles to one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a small comment, usually you don't want to use `blockingGet`. Instead you use other combinators to compose your solution and in the end you use subscribe to evaluate it.

I'm assuming you want to combine multiple calls that return a `Single` where the result of the next call depends on the previous.

The combinator you are looking for is `flatMap`.

```
val user: Single<User> = getUser()
val singleOfSomething: Single<Conversation> = user.flatMap { user-> 
    getConversation(user).flatMap {conversation -> 
        someMethod(user, conversation) 
    }
}
```

here the return type would be `Single` of whatever `someMethod` returns.

You would use `subscribe` to get that value out when you need it.